# find all x such that $2^x - 1$ and $2^x + 1$ are prime

Tags: number-theory

Find all $x$ such that $2^x - 1$ and $2^x + 1$ are prime. I don't even know where to start.  All I can figure out is that $(2^x - 1, 2^x + 1) =1$.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming that $x$ is a natural number, it's quite trivial, since $2^x-1,\ 2^x,\ 2^x+1$ are three consecutive numbers, so one of them is divisible by 3, and it obviously isn't $2^x$.

3 is the only prime divisible by 3, so:

$2^x-1=3$ leads to $x=2$ - good ($2^x+1=5$ - prime).

$2^x+1=3$ leads to $x=1$ - contradiction ($2^x-1=1$ - not prime).

EDIT:
Since the Mersenne prime problem is an open conjecture, 
I assumed the author means both numbers togoether prime.

Answer (score 2):

One way to go about this is to determine when $2^n-1$ and $2^n+1$ are individually prime. For the first case, try to show that $n$ must be a prime number. For the second case, try to show that $n$ must be a power of $2$. What can you conclude?

Answer (score 0):

If $x$ is odd, there we can apply the factoring formula of $a^x + b^x$ to show that $2^x+1$ is divisible by $3$. If $x$ is even, you can factor $2^x-1$ and see that $x$ must be $2$.